# How to remove wildcard character from field

Tags: mariadb

I have fields that contain the character `*`. I've been trying to remove them but my commands fail with an error...

Example:

```
UPDATE name SET name = REGEXP_REPLACE (name, '*', '') WHERE category_id = 168;
```

I'm also struggling to remove other characters like `|`

Comment: * has a special meaning in regular expression language (zero or more occurrences). Try escaping it like: `REGEXP_REPLACE (name, '\*', '')`

Comment: I tried, but that also doesn't work @Lennart

Comment: Try `'[*]'` ; that is, use a "character class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparantly the quote should be `\\`:

```
UPDATE name SET name = REGEXP_REPLACE (name, '\\*', '');
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=235fb5c14e9313e097eed0747cab16ad)